# Convex-Constrained Nonconvex-Nonconcave Minimax Problem

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, non-convex-optimization

In the mathematical optimization theory, I have taken a glance at many papers which deal with the unconstrained convex-concave or nonconvex-concave minimax optimization, i.e.,

$$
\min_{x\in X}\ \max_{y\in Y}\ f(x,y),
$$

where the function $f\colon X\times Y\to \Re$ is nonconvex and nonconcave w.r.t. x and y, respectively, and also is continuously differentiable (ONLY ONCE), and the sets $X$ and $Y$ are convex on the Euclidean space.

However, I cannot find a paper that treats convex-constrained nonconvex-nonconcave minimax problem.
So, for such problems, I want to ask that

**Do you know an algorithm that guarantees global convergence?**

I have also searched from the perspective of the semi-infinite programming.
This is because this minimax problem can be reformulated as follows by the epigraphical expression:

$$
\begin{array}{cl}
\displaystyle\min_{x\in X, x_0} & x_0\\
\text{subject to} & x_0\geq f(x,y)\quad\forall y\in Y.
\end{array}
$$

But in this field of studies also, many studies assume convexity of $f$ or sufficient smoothness of $f$.

I do NOT require the efficiency of computation.
I want to implement an algorithm that is **surely convergent** to some points, not necessarily converges to a global optimal (saddle) point.

Thank you.

Comment: It won't be hard to construct a *convergent* algorithm (e.g. just take sufficiently diminishing step-sizes), but I'm not aware of an algorithm which globally converges to something meaningful for the nonconvex case. I think in-practice folks use heuristic algorithms for this setting, and often they'll produce a point which is "good enough", but may not be a global solution.

Comment: [Here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2192440621000034) is a recent review on global optimization for nonconvex semi-infinite programming that might be useful. And [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.10207v1.pdf) is a paper that deals with "local optimization" for the nonconvex and nonconcave setting (but with some other assumptions).

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked two years ago and now we observe more progress in this field. There are several works that dealt with structured nonconvex-nonconcave settings but I found this recent work [1] has the most significant results. Basically, if you assume your constraint set $Y$ is convex and compact, then they are the first to provide convergence for any Lipschitz smooth functions toward a "stationary point" (see their Definition 1, also see [2] for comparisons of different notion of optimal points). See their reference for previous works on structured nonconvex-nonconcave games.

I didn't check the detail proof of [1] yet. Feel free to correct me if I made wrong claims in the last paragraph.

References:

[1] Liu, Yuanyuan, et al. "A Single-Loop Accelerated Extra-Gradient Difference Algorithm with Improved Complexity Bounds for Constrained Minimax Optimization." Thirty-seventh Conference on Neural Information Processing Systems. 2023.

[2] Jin, Chi, Praneeth Netrapalli, and Michael Jordan. "What is local optimality in nonconvex-nonconcave minimax optimization?." International conference on machine learning. PMLR, 2020.